# Argument list for class template `sgl::Bag` is missing

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++20

So I am currently working on a project to make a library with all of the different data structures in C++. Here I have declared a class `Bag`:

```
template<typename Type>
class Bag
{
    // ...
    inline static const char* print_seperator = "\n";

public:

    // ...
    inline static void set_seperator(const char* new_seperator)
    {
        Bag::print_seperator = new_seperator;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, but when I try to use it in my `main()` function like this:

```
sgl::Bag::set_seperator(", ");
```

This shows the following error:

> Argument list for class template `sgl::Bag` is missing

..so I gave the argument list for the class template:

```
sgl::Bag<int>::set_seperator(", ");
```

..and it works fine.

But I don't want to type that out every time. Is there any way I can overcome this?

Comment: You can use **default template argument** `template<typename Type = int>
class Bag {//code here as before};  int main() {Bag<>::set_seperator(", ");}`

Comment: @AnoopRana Can I get a quick example of that? Because I have tried `template<typename Type = int>` already and It didn't really seem to work.

Comment: See [Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KCIrT8pn2) in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **default template argument** for the template type parameter `Type` as shown below:

```
//use default argument for template type parameter "Type"
template<typename Type = int>
class Bag
{
    // ...
    inline static const char* print_seperator = "\n";

public:

    // ...
    inline static void set_seperator(const char* new_seperator)
    {
        Bag::print_seperator = new_seperator;
    }
};
int main()
{
    //no need to specify int
    Bag<>::set_seperator(", "); //angle bracket still needed  
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KCIrT8pn2)